# Enter key form submit not working when Link is present

Tags: reactjs, form-submit, reactstrap

I am unable to submit form on enter key press

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>

    <Link to="/back"><Button> Back</Button></Link> // back button

    <FormGroup>
        <Label htmlFor="name">Name</Label>
        <Input name="name" type="text"/>
    </FormGroup>

    <Button type="submit"><i className="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit</Button>
    <Button type="reset" onClick={this.HandleReset}><i className="fa fa-ban"></i> Reset</Button>

</Form>
```

Enter key must trigger this function

```
handleFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // more core here
}
```

When i press enter key the back button in the form with the link is executing.

When i comment the back button it is working properly i.e form is getting submitted (and i can control it using preventDefault()).

How can i use form onSubmit while link is present in the form ?

Comment: There's not enough information to help, but I would try placing the `<Link />` at the end of your `<Form />`. If that solved your problem, you can infer that when <Link /> is the first element, it is the first _interactive_ element, and pressing enter clicks that instead of your submit button. Cheers.

Comment: @BhargavShah But i cant place button any place. why should i change ui of form. Also i can use enter key press event and then submit that form but that is not generic solution.

Comment: You should not, that was to debug and find the problem. If you give more information, possibly an online REPL with your setup, I'll be able to help you better.

Comment: @BhargavShah yes, when i change its position its working also when i delete/comment back button code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just take the `Link` outside the `Form` component? The `Link` doesn't provide any value or meet any requirements for the form in a purely functional perspective. The `Form` is meant to gather input from the user. The `Link` is merely a back button, let it be a back button.

For aesthetic purposes, the differences are negligible.

```
  <div>
    <Link to="/back"><Button> Back</Button></Link> // back button
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <FormGroup>
            <Label htmlFor="name">Name</Label>
            <Input name="name" type="text"/>
        </FormGroup>

        <Button type="submit"><i className="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit</Button>
        <Button type="reset" onClick={this.HandleReset}><i className="fa fa-ban"></i> Reset</Button>
    </Form>
  </div>
```

Because when you define a button in a form, it implicitly has a type of "submit". Since you have a button in your `Link`, and it is the first button in the form, your form decides that this is the button that will execute on form submission. Thus ignoring your actual submit button on the bottom.

You can workaround this by giving the button in the `Link` tag a type of "button" as you suggested. Thus the form will travel further down to find another button.

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
    <Link to="/back"><Button type="button"> Back</Button></Link> // back button
    <FormGroup>
        <Label htmlFor="name">Name</Label>
        <Input name="name" type="text"/>
    </FormGroup>
    <Button type="submit"><i className="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit</Button>
    <Button type="reset" onClick={this.HandleReset}><i className="fa fa-ban"></i> Reset</Button>
</Form>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why it is functioning in this way? why it is triggering first button of form

Comment: @LulzAsh because when you define button in a form, it implicitly has a type of "submit". Since you have a button in your Link, and it is the first button in the form. Your form decides that this is the button that will execute on form submission. Thus ignoring your actual submit button on the bottom.

Comment: yes !!! The button is a submit button (this is default for all browsers, except Internet Explorer).

Comment: Nice. Looks like you did some research on your own. @LulzAsh :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions :

- Changing the position of the button, Button must not be first element
  inside the form.
- Placing button outside the form element.
- Binding an event to enter key and then submit the form from event.
- Adding `type="button"` property to the button without changing its
  position.